# How can I move a panel's position to the top in my JSF application?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a panelGrid with two columns - each one of them with a panel. Both panels have dataTables and are side by side.

```
<h:panelGrid id="png31" columns="2">
<p:panel id="pnlCab" header="Cabecera">
    <p:commandButton value="Nueva actividad" type="button" id="actiNue" onclick="PF('wdlgAgregar').show()"/>
    <br /> <br />
    <p:dataTable id="dataCabecera" value="#{cargaHorariaController.listaActivDoc}">
        <!-- Elements -->
    </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>

<p:panel id="pnlDet" header="Detalle">
    <p:commandButton value="Nueva subactividad" type="button" id="subactiNue" onclick="PF('wdlgAgregarS').show()">
        <p:ajax update="cmbSubNue" listener="#{cargaHorariaController.cargarSubactividades()}" />
    </p:commandButton>
    <br /> <br />
    <p:dataTable id="dataDetalle" value="#{cargaHorariaController.listaSubactividad}">
        <!-- Elements -->
    </p:dataTable>
</p:panel>
```

When the datatables are empty, both panels are at the top, but when one of them displays records, the panel with the empty dataTable aligns vertically to the middle of the panel with the filled dataTable.

[image]

What can I do so both panels are always at the top, even with filled dataTables?

Comment: I would use rendered attribute and hide panel if there is no data to show.

Comment: Did you try CSS `vertical-align:top`?

Comment: Please learn some basic css... It **is** 'required' when doing webdevelopment. Client-side it is all html and css... all... oh and javascript

Comment: @Kukeltje, I can't modify the CSS, because the institution uses a template that I have to adapt to.

Comment: Sorry, but this is real BS... You are effectively saying: _"I need to move this to the top, but I cannot do it since I'm not allowed to..."_ You can always add some small css in your page just for this. If you can't/are not allowed, please ask your superior (boss?) to join in in this conversation and we'll convince him to listen to you and fire the person that told you to not use/change/add some small relevant CSS

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<style type="text/css">
     .my-style td{
        vertical-align: text-top !important;
      }
</style>

<h:panelGrid id="png31" columns="2" columnClasses="width: 40%, width: 60%"
             styleClass="my-style" >
      <p:panel> 
             ........
      </p:panel>
      .......
      .......
      .......
</h:panelGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS classes:

```
.col1 {
width: 40%;
vertical-align: top;
}

.col2 {
width: 60%;
vertical-align: top;
}
```

and change

```
<h:panelGrid id="png31" columns="2" columnClasses="col1, col2">
```